# Al intentar validar una contraseña ingresada por un textField, solo da el mensaje del showMessage

Tags: java

Tengo mi método validarContraseña y quiero que lo valide al dar a un botón de registrarse, y si es posible usar un try catch o genéricos para usar la misma función y validar otros aspectos de una página para registrarse.

```
public  boolean validarContraseña(String contraseña){
        contraseña = txtContraseña.getText();
            
        if (contraseña.length()>8){
            boolean mayuscula = false;
            boolean numero = false;
            boolean space = false;
            char c;
            for (int i =0; i<contraseña.length(); i++ ){
                c = contraseña.charAt(i);
                // Character Verifica si en c hay un numero 
                if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                    numero = true;
                }
                if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                    mayuscula = true;
                }
                if(Character.isWhitespace(c)){
                    space = false;
                }
                
            }//for Validar 
            if(numero && mayuscula && space)
                return true;
            else
                return false;   
            }else{
                return false;
        }
        
    }
//

private void btnUnirseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       //Excepciones
       String contraseña="", name="",ape="",dire="";
       contraseña = txtContraseña.getText();
       // Name
           if(name.equals("")){
            showMessageDialog(this,"Falta Nombre");
            txtNombre.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
            }
        //Sexo
           
        //Contraseña
        if (validarContraseña(contraseña)){
        }else{
            showMessageDialog(this,"Contraseña no segura, debe tener mas de 8 digitos, blablalba");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has depurado? ¿Qué valor estás escribiendo en el TextField?

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar un bloque try-catch para manejar las excepciones al llamar a la función validarContraseña o también puedes modificar tu funcion validarContraseña para que acepte parametros adicionales y realice la validacion especifica que necesites
una forma seria agregar un bloque try catch para capturar las excepciones y msotrar mensaje. tambien agregar variables como nombre. puedes agregar mas variables para capturar los demás campos. remplzar txtNombre con los nombres de variables te dejo un ejemplo con tu codigo amigo:

```
public boolean validarContraseña(String contraseña) {
 if (contraseña.length() > 8) {
    boolean mayuscula = false;
    boolean numero = false;
    boolean espacio = false;
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < contraseña.length(); i++) {
        c = contraseña.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            numero = true;
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            mayuscula = true;
        }

        if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            espacio = true;
        }
     }

    return numero && mayuscula && !espacio;
 } else {
    return false;
 }
}

    private void btnUnirseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     String contraseña = txtContraseña.getText();
     String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
    // otros campos

     try {
      if (validarContraseña(contraseña)) {
        // Validación exitosa, realizar el registro
     } else {
        showMessageDialog(this, "Contraseña no segura. Debe tener más de 8 
     dígitos y contener al menos una mayúscula, un número y no puede 
     contener espacios.");
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    showMessageDialog(this, "Error al validar contraseña: " + 
    e.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

Comment: dale formato a esto

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnUnirseActionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt ) {
       // obtenemos los datos, verificamos que tengan contenido, si no, enviamos el 
       // mensaje correspondiente, y al final de los if, salimos de la función.  
    String contraseña = txtContraseña.getText();
    String name = txtNombre.getText();
    String edad = txtEdad.getText();
    boolean retornar = false;
    if( name.equals( "" ) ) {
       System.out.println( "Falta Nombre" );
       retornar = true;
    }
    if( contraseña.equals( "" ) ) {
       System.out.println( "Falta contraseña" );
       retornar = true;
    }
    if( edad.equals( "" ) ) {
       System.out.println( "Falta edad" );
       retornar = true;
    }
    if( retornar ) {
       return;
    }

       // inicializamos el array, con la devolución de **validarCampos**, que luego
       // usaremos para generar los mensajes de error.
    boolean validos[] = validarCampos( contraseña, name, edad );
    if( validos[ 0 ] ) {
       System.out.println( "Contraseña no segura, debe tener mas de 8 digitos, blablalba" );
    }
    if( validos[ 1 ] ) {
       System.out.println( "El nombre solo puede contener letras" );
    }
    if( validos[ 2 ] ) {
       System.out.println( "Por favor ingrese un número válido" );
    }
}

public boolean[] validarCampos( String contraseña, String nombre, String edad ) {

      // creamos tres variables que no indicarán si cada campo es válido, realicé algunos 
      // cambios menores en la lógica, que presentaba errores
   boolean contraseñaNoOk = true;
   boolean nombreNoOk = true;
   boolean edadNoOk = true;
   if( contraseña.length() < 8 ) {
      contraseñaNoOk = true;
   }
   else {
      boolean mayuscula = false;
      boolean numero = false;
      boolean space = true;
      char c;
      for( int i = 0; i < contraseña.length(); i++ ) {
         c = contraseña.charAt( i );
         System.out.println( c );
         if( Character.isDigit( c ) ) {
            numero = true;
         }
         if( Character.isUpperCase( c ) ) {
            mayuscula = true;
         }
         if( Character.isWhitespace( c ) ) {
            space = false;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(  numero + " " + mayuscula + " " + space);
      if( numero && mayuscula && space ) {
         contraseñaNoOk = false;
      }
   }
   if( nombre.matches( "[A-Za-z]{1,}" ) ) {
      nombreNoOk = false;
   }
   try {
      int e = Integer.parseInt( edad );
      edadNoOk = false;
   }
   catch( Exception e ) {  }
   boolean salida[] = { contraseñaNoOk, nombreNoOk, edadNoOk };
   return salida;
}
```

Nota, cuando subí la respuesta, me dí cuenta que uno de los campos era **sexo**... yo puse **edad**, debe ser que ya ni  me acuerdo jaja.
Espero que mi respuesta te ayude.